# Why this Javascript RegExp is returning true?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate alpha characters (in a request, node.js) and what i used was:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/.test(input)
```

BUT when a value null was passed, then it was validated OK (regexp returns TRUE)
example:

```
/[a-zA-Z]+/.test(null) // <--- this returns true :(
```

Somebody can explain me this? i need to avoid nulls, thanks!

Comment: it's testing `"null"`, not `null`

Comment: no, i was testing null, not "null", please use chrome console and type this:
    /[a-zA-Z]+/.test(null)

Comment: no, you were testing `"null"`; js converts it to a string for the test() method...

Comment: Yes, i know it by now, thanks for your help dandavis!!!!  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular
>   expression and a specified string. Returns true or false

[`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) converts parameters passed to a `String`

For example `/\d/.test(0)` would also return `true`, as expected, where `0` is a `Number` passed as parameter.

Comment: Ohh my god, thank you very much!! :) that helps a lot :D

Answer (score 2):

Because .test() coerces the parameter to a string, you are effectively testing against 'null' - which evaluates to true.